# How to add an IOS platform that can build in swift 4 with Ionic cordova platform add?

Tags: cordova, swift3, swift4, ionic4, xcode10.2

I have ported and Ionic 3 app into Ionic 4 and updated a lot of my dependencies. My Ionic 4 app runs perfectly in the browser. Last week, I updated my Xcode from 10.1 to 10.2. Xcode dropped support for Swift 3 in the update and ionic cordova seems to only be able to export a project in swift 3. As a result, my app is no longer working in the Xcode simulator.

I have tried updating Ionic 4 and Cordova to their latest versions and then deploying my code to IOS without being version specific. I only ran `$ ionic cordova add ios` and it still builds the project in Swift 3. In a Hail Mary attempt to try to trouble shoot the issue in Xcode, I manually changed the projects language to Swift 4 via the build settings. I got one fatal deprecated error which I allowed Xcode's FIXME button to resolve. After that, the simulator was able to load the Ionic 4 app... but all of my API based requests are not working.

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/Users/tavosoto/.nvm/versions/node/v11.7.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.2.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 5.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 15 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/tavosoto/Library/Android/sdk/)
   ios-sim           : 7.0.0
   NodeJS            : v11.7.0 (/Users/tavosoto/.nvm/versions/node/v11.7.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.5.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2 Build version 10E125
```

API request error thrown while in Simulator:

```
ERROR: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"https://example.com/api/v1/legal","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://example.com/api/v1/legal: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

Expected result is that Ionic 4 and Cordova can successfully export an IOS platform in Swift 4 in order to support the deprecation of Swift 3 in Xcode 10.2.